# Add additional object keys into array based on condition javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

My array:

```
[
  {
    name: 'test1',
    state: 'OK',
    status: true,
    pending: 33,
    approved: 0,
    active: 0,
    inactive: 33
  },
  {
    name: 'test3',
    state: 'OK',
    status: true,
    pending: 33,
    approved: 0,
    active: 0,
    inactive: 33
  },
  {
    name: 'test4',
    state: 'OK',
    status: true
  }
]
```

If the "pending", "approved", "active", "inactive" key not exists in object, i need output like this:

Expected output:

```
[
  {
    name: 'test1',
    state: 'OK',
    status: true,
    pending: 33,
    approved: 0,
    active: 0,
    inactive: 33
  },
  {
    name: 'test3',
    state: 'OK',
    status: true,
    pending: 33,
    approved: 0,
    active: 0,
    inactive: 33
  },
  {
    name: 'test4',
    state: 'OK',
    status: true,
    pending: 0,
    approved: 0,
    active: 0,
    inactive: 0
  }
]
```

How to do this?

I tried with map but i dont know how to set condition.

I want to set the values into zero.

Comment: can you include your attempt(s) in your question please? Thank you.

Comment: ok wait........

Comment: http://jsbin.com/yimebifoci/edit?js,output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Array.map()` and use an array of properties, iterate over the array of properties and check for each object if that property is present in the object or not, if it is not present than simply add  the  property and assign it value as 0.

```js
let arr = [ { name: 'test1', state: 'OK', status: true, pending: 33, approved: 0, active: 0, inactive: 33 }, { name: 'test3', state: 'OK', status: true, pending: 33, approved: 0, active: 0, inactive: 33 }, { name: 'test4', state: 'OK', status: true } ];
let props = ['active','inactive', 'approved', 'pending'];
let result = arr.map(a =>{
  props.forEach(prop=>  a[prop] = a[prop] || 0);
  return a;
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.forEach` to apply your condition to each object.

```js
arr = [
  {
    name: 'test1',
    state: 'OK',
    status: true,
    pending: 33,
    approved: 0,
    active: 0,
    inactive: 33
  },
  {
    name: 'test3',
    state: 'OK',
    status: true,
    pending: 33,
    approved: 0,
    active: 0,
    inactive: 33
  },
  {
    name: 'test4',
    state: 'OK',
    status: true
  }
]

arr.forEach(obj => {for (let p of ['pending', 'approved', 'active', 'inactive']){
                        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(p)){
                            obj[p] = 0;
                        }
                   }});

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

- Create an object having properties with their default values.
- Use `.map()` to iterate over objects of the given array by passing a callback.
- Use `Object.assign()` method to create a close of the current object by passing an empty object, default object and current object as arguments. First defaults values will be copied into empty object and then `Object.assign()` will copy each property from the current object in the cloned effectively overriding the default values.

Below is a demo:

```js
let data = [
  {name: 'test1',state:'OK',status:true,pending: 33,approved: 0,active: 0,inactive: 33},
  {name: 'test3',state:'OK',status:true,pending: 33,approved: 0,active: 0,inactive: 33},
  {name: 'test4',state:'OK',status:true}
];

let defaults = {
  pending: 0,
  approved: 0,
  inactive: 0,
  active: 0
};

let result = data.map(o => Object.assign({}, defaults, o));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**Resources:**

- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)